# Better way? Sharepoint online Provider Hosted app using azure web site or using IIS?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Soon our organization is moving to SharePoint online.We have so many custom solutions which we want to move to SharePoint online and we are planning to use provider hosted apps as we are pulling most of our data from SQL DB. Now I want to know which approach would be better for hosting web app part:

1) Azure

2) IIS server

Comment: Both are valid and both have their own sets of advantages and disadvantages. Connectivity with SQL is obviously going to be a factor in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay as Derek said. It really depends on how much freedom you require over application configuration control. Azure is best when you don't need this freedom and would prefer to focus on your applications.

Some IIS Server advantages over Azure.

1. Remote desktop to IIS server to troubleshoot. Example checking IIS log files, event logs.
2. Full web site configuration control. Example Url Redirects, Mime Types etc.

Some Azure advantages over IIS.

1. No worry of backup/restore/server crash or any other server related issues. Microsoft manages all this.
2. No website configuration. Basic website configuration is done by Azure.